# Smarter ways to remove id's from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

This is what I have now. Looked around and didnt see anything that popped out at me. Is there a better performing way to remove/delete my object in `myArray` don't exist in `data` by ID?

```
for (m in myArray) {
    var found = false;
    _.each(data, function (p) {
        if (p.id === m) {
            found = true;
        }
    });
    if (!found) {
        myArray[m].remove();
        delete myArray[m];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply want to remove array elements who are not contained in `data`. Why not just filter them?

```
ids = _(data).pluck('id');
myArray = _(myArray).filter(function(x) {
  return _(ids).include(x);
})
```